# Why do people use .env file on server?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Why do people put a `.env` file to store all their secrets in a server? If someone hacks it, isn't the `.env` equally accessible as all the other files? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that storing environmental secrets in a `.env` file poses a risk of plain text secrets being exposed to a third party if they gained access to raw code.

Just like other areas with sensitive material there are ways to get around this, generally an approach that people might take it to use a secrets management system which instead replaces any secrets values from a `.env` file to be accessed via a validated request.

AWS supports a couple of official services that can do this:

- [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) - This service is specifically built for this purpose, you define a secret and give it either a string or JSON value that is then retrieved via a call using the SDK. All values are encrypted using a KMS key.
- [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) - Similar to secrets manager, you provide a key name and give it a value. It supports both unencrypted and encrypted values (use [SecureString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-securestring.html) type).

In addition there are other services such as [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) that provide similar functionality.

For environmental configuration a `.env` file can still be appropriate i.e. enable this feature flag but if you want to try and reduce the blast radius of your application then storing secrets outside a plain text file will help to reduce this risk.

Comment: Thanks for this response! I am aware of AWS Secrets Manager, but just wanted to know why people even use `.envs` in the first place

Comment: Its down to personal preference, but I would guess because it's fairly easy. For a lot of cases it is fine if you do not have sensitive information and simply want to just enable flags. However, over time people will just use what they already have without always considering the risks :(

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thank you! One last thing -- I am new to this -- what do you mean by flags?

Comment: By flags I just mean for example you might have a flag to enable a feature, perhaps in an A/B test. For example a flag to enable a new design for a particular page etc

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, have a great day :)

Answer (score 4):

That is not the main reason for using environment variables. However, it is secure enough for saving secret values too especially when they’re combined with hashing methods.

Environment variables are most useful in the actual production level of programming. Your application must have different environments to run upon. Development: that your host is local and as a developer you need to test your code and set the debug variable to true to get stateful errors which is not something you want on the production environment. Production: that your host is your domain or server IP and you need different middleware than of the development stage. There are also staging and test environments for bigger projects. There could be a lot of things that should be handled differently on different environments: database is a great example. Besides, environment variables are useful for when there is more than one person working with the code base and people can configure the project based on their machine/OS using environment variables.